# Were Nayanars foretold in any of the Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, shaiva-siddhanta, nayanar

Vaishnavas say [Bhagavata Purana](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/5/38-40) foretold the upcoming of Alwars. Likewise, any Hindu scriptures predict the upcoming of Nayanars?

For those who aren't familiar with [Alwars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvars) and [Nayanars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nayanars) - they are the poet-saint devotees of Vishnu and poet-saint devotees of Shiva respectively. Together, they were 75 (12 and 63 respectively) in number. They traveled the land, spreading Bhakti through their literature and songs.